# #1415 Error phpmyadmin on trigger creation

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to write trigger into PHPMyAdmin but it doesn't work.
The code is the following:

```
select*,  1459630_form_1 concat (segmento_auto_richiesto, ' , ', alimentazione) as mkt
```

When I run the code, I always get this error:

> #1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger.

I'm trying to execute this query every time a new record is immetted in the table. Coul'd someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: And what is unclear in the error message? *I'm trying to execute this query every time a new record is immetted in the table.* Only DML over another table or SELECT into variable allowed in a trigger.

Comment: *The code is the following* This is not trigger code, this is a part of it. Provide complete code.

Comment: The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`Sql1459630`@`%` TRIGGER `mkt` BEFORE INSERT ON `1459630_form_1` FOR EACH ROW select*, concat (segmento_auto_richiesto, ' , ', alimentazione) as mkt from 1459630_form_1"
Messaggio di MySQL: #1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Comment: Trigger is simple error message is clear, you cannot do this. If you can tell us why you are trying to do something this way we can perhaps suggest an alternative.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Formtools to collect marketing data, and I need a new colum with some concatenated values. This because I need a new format file, like CSV or XML, that will be automatically exported into an FTP process

Comment: Have you considered generated column? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: Sure but also I need that this will happen every time a new record is submitted

Comment: *I need a new format file, like CSV or XML, that will be automatically exported into an FTP process* O_O For each insert??? imagine that you insert 1000 rows in a query (INSERT .. SELECT) - do you really need 1000 consecutive exports during this insertion?

Comment: Possible solution: (1) Trigger inserts some data about the insertion into service table. (2) Event procedure (executed, for example, daily) reads service table, performs needed action over its data (for example, exports the rows mentioned in service table from working table to CSV file) and truncated service table.

Comment: Not for each insert. I mean a daily update to upload files into the database. I think it's possible change the code inside the Formtools script via PHP and create a hidden field whit all the values separated with comma.